# ASP.NET Master Page in separate assembly

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have some ASP.NET Master Pages located in one assembly. I need to use these Master Pages with my WebForm pages located in other assemblies that have a reference to the first assembly. I cannot seem to figure out a way to do this.

Is there a nice way that I can do this?

If no pretty solution exists I would also like to hear about possible hacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Master Pages are based upon Usercontrols, therefore they cannot be shared across applications.

That said, Dan Wahlin has a way around that particular limitation [listed on his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2005/11/16/430779.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[Sharing Master Pages Across IIS Applications](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2005/11/16/430779.aspx) by Dan Wahlin will give you some ideas..

Also, check this [excellent article](http://odetocode.com/Articles/450.aspx) by Scott Allen. You can check the last section at the end on sharing master pages.

Answer (score 1):

There are no pretty solutions to this problem.

What you can do is put it into a separate web application project and pre-compile it.  Then take the precompiled dlls and ILMerge them into a single dll that you can reference in your app.

The actual master page that you reference will have a class name like this:  MyMasterPage_aweknk so look it up in reflector.  The class that looks like "MyMasterPage" is really just the code-behind.

It's really disgusting, but it's what we've done to reuse user controls in multiple applications.